# How to group typeclass in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The intention is to make the type class constraint code cleaner.

```
type CanThrowDice = (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a)

throwDice :: CanThrowDice m a => (a, a) -> m a
throwDice (r1, r2) = ...
```

instead of writing:

```
throwDice ::  (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a) => (a, a) -> m a
throwDice (r1, r2) = ...
```

I remember seeing this usage somewhere but can't recall.
The above code warns to me add some extra pragma such as `ConstraintKinds` which I can't make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that is missing are the type parameters `m` and `a` and the [**`ConstraintKinds`** language pragma [ghc-doc]](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/constraint_kind.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

--                ↓ ↓ type parameters
type CanThrowDice m a = (Monad m, MonadIO m, Random a)

throwDice :: CanThrowDice m a => (a, a) -> m a
throwDice (r1, r2) = …
```